# How can I set S3 putObject options when using signed URL's to upload files from the client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using signed urls to upload files directly from the client straight into my S3 bucket.  To do this I perform a direct put request to upload the file itself after having creating a signed URL of the command I want to perform.

I create the signed url like so:

```
      $command = $s3->getCommand('PutObject', array(
                    'Bucket' => $this->_bucket,
                    'Key' => $key,
                    'ACL' => 'public-read',
                    'CacheControl' => 'max-age=0',
                    'ContentEncoding' => 'gzip',
                    'ContentType' => $filetype,
                    'Body' => '',
                    'ContentMD5' => false
                ));


 $signedUrl = $command->createPresignedUrl('+6 hours');
```

However, after then performing the put request and uploading the file itself the `Cache-Control` and `Content-Encoding` headers are not set.

Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers still have to be set in the `PUT` request.  Including them in the signed url isn't sufficient.

The pre-signed URL only serves to ensure that the *actual* request parameters match the *authorized* request parameters (otherwise the request fails).

So, if what I am saying is correct, then if these parameters aren't being sent with the request, it should fail, right?  Almost.

Unfortunately, V2 authentication does not validate all request headers, such as `Content-Encoding` for example:

> Note how only the Content-Type and Content-MD5 HTTP entity headers appear in the StringToSign. The other Content-* entity headers do not.
>
> — http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

The same is true for `Cache-Control`.  Only `x-amz-*` headers are subject to validation against the signature provided in V2 (which uses `&Signature=` in the Query string).

V4 auth (which, by contrast, uses `&X-Amz-Signature=` in the query string) contains a mechanism allowing you to specify which headers need validation against the signature, but in either case, you have to send the headers with the actual request itself, not just include them in the signature.  It appears that you aren't, and that's why they are not set.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question completely. I'm struggling to find a good example of how to authorize a request using the V4 auth via the PHP sdk.  Do you by any chance have the ainformation to hand?  Regardless, thans for your help.

Comment: @gordyr I don't use the SDKs because I don't like to have the unnecessary barrier between me and the REST API, so I write all of my own libraries and code... but it looks like you will need something along the lines of `$s3 = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array('signature' => 'v4'));` ... http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html ... although beyond simply enabling V4, there may be additional steps needed, in order to specify which headers you want it include in the signature.  I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, i finally got there.  Cheers :)